# How to check time difference in IF controller?

Tags: jmeter

I am testing the web application where I need to generate the token ID in every 15 minutes.

I assign the current time and current time + 15 minutes in the following two variables in the bean shell sampler.This will assign the datetime in milliseconds to the respective variables.

String StartTime = "${__timeShift(,,,,)}";
String EndTime = "${__timeShift(,,PT15M,,)}";

Now I want to compare the time difference in the IF controller. If the time difference is 15 minutes (900000 ms) then IF controller should execute for the token id generation.

I used __eval function like below in the IF controller which is not working.

```
${__eval(${EndTime})} - ${__eval(${StartTime})}  >= 900000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're violating JMeter Best Practices, to wit:

1. Using Beanshell for scripting while [since JMeter 3.1 users are encouraged to switch to JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
2. Using JavaScript in the If Controller while [documentation clearly states](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) that:

   > For performance it is advised to check `Interpret Condition as Variable Expression` and use `__jexl3` or `__groovy` evaluating to true or false or a variable that contains true or false. `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` can be used to test if last sampler was successful
3. You're inlining [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into a script which is not the best idea as the function might resolve into something which causes compilation failure.
4. I also fail to see where you're setting the relevant JMeter Variables using `vars` shorthand.

---

Assuming all above:

1. Switch to the [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and use the following code:

   ```
   def StartTime = new Date() 
   use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
       def EndTime = StartTime + 15.minutes
       vars.put("StartTime", StartTime.getTime() as String)
        vars.put("EndTime", EndTime.getTime() as String)
   }
   ```
2. In the If Controller use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

   ```
   ${__groovy((vars.get('EndTime') as long) - (vars.get('StartTime') as long) >= 90000,)}
   ```

   Overall If Controller Configuration just in case:

   [image]
3. Check out [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) article if anything remains unclear

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression with [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller):

```
${EndTime} - ${StartTime} >= 900000
```

You may check [my test plan example](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/78128#testDetails), it's work for me.